# Bootstrap modal with background fading in

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 1.4.0 and jquery 1.7.2. I'm trying to create a modal window with fading background. The modal window should be loaded using javascript function.

Here's the code I have:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="error-dialog" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h1 class="exp-heading">Error</h1>
    <p class="exp-para pad-btm"> {$meta.message}</p>
    <!-- apps go here -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!-- apps end here --> 
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer"  align="center"><a href="#" data-controls-modal-close="error-dialog" ><img src="images/cancel_btn.png" alt="" border="0" align="middle" /></a> </div>
</div>

<script language="Javascript">  
$('#error-dialog').modal('show');                                                                   
</script>
```

The modal is showing but the background is not fading in.
The CSS file is the default one 1.4.0/bootstrap.css

Comment: I don't know, but I'd stick with [Bootstrap 2.1.0](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) and follow their docs.

Comment: What browser are you testing on? The Modal plugin (1.4 or 2.x) uses CSS3 transitions, so if your browser doesn't support them (e.g. IE9), you're not going to see a fade. Otherwise, I also endorse @moonwave99's sentiment - try to use at least 2.x.  They've made significant improvements to the modal in particular since 1.4.

Comment: Chrome 21. The thing is I can't change the bootstrap version, I'm not the right person in the team who can do that :-/

Comment: Kenny, do you mean you want a fade effect for the backdrop? Anyway, I agree with merv and moon

Comment: Gary, yeah. That's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if you are trying to fade in the image you need to utilize the

```
.fadeIn()
```

method