# Modal under background fade bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Related Links**
1) [Bootstrap modal appearing under background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background)

[Bootstrap modal with background fading in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129682/bootstrap-modal-with-background-fading-in)

[Twitter Bootstrap - why is my modal as faded as the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367334/twitter-bootstrap-why-is-my-modal-as-faded-as-the-background)

**Error**
http://jsfiddle.net/jononomo/7z8RZ/7/

image

[image]

**CSS/JS**

```
     <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

**Code**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Signup</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

*This is an Asp.Net MVC4 Application*

This fade error is removed if i remove navigation bar css `navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top` but the modal location is still on left side

all the above related links define same problem but none of them help to solve mine

Comment: Do you have any custom css in the project that we can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your example `navbar navbar-fixed-top` need `z-index > 1040`

Comment: Thanks bro this did solve my problem but what about location/position error because in some page it is showing on correct location but on some page its on left and cut

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this

```
<!--===================navBar===================-->
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"> 
<a href="#registration_modal" data-toggle="modal">
    Register
</a>
</div>
<!--===================modal====================-->
<div id="registration_modal" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3>Register An Account</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        Registration form goes here.
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/7z8RZ/55/

Comment: bro its a huge project and many files are inherited from diff location
it is impossible to just change code to above